# Changing logos of site based on class - PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my header.php to change the website's logo based on the page's slug:

```
$logo_img = 'default'; 
    if (is_page('brookside')) {
        $logo_img = 'brookside'; 
    } elseif (is_page('hilltop')) {
        $logo_img = 'hilltop'; 
    } elseif (is_page('reserve')) {
        $logo_img = 'reserve'; 
    }
```

Which works great. However, the pages a need to change the logo are query string URL, so they don't have slugs. I was able to add a unique class to each page. My question is:

How do I translate that code to "if a page has "x" class? So, what function should I use instead of `is_page`?

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the different urls for example?

Comment: The functionality works just fine. But instead of using page slug (is_page) I would like to use "if body hasClass" or something like that.

Comment: URL: `http://reserveatbrooksidemeadowsmhc.com/?ct_additional_features=brookside&search-listings=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if($_GET['ct_additional_features'] == 'brookside') {
    $logo_img = 'brookside';
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @Dekel !

Answer (score 0):

You could use [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) that outputs the Class Name and there solve your `if` with what are you saying

Comment: I'm almost sure he is not talking about PHP classes, but wordpress classes (that are related to css).

Comment: @P0lT10n Thanks! How would I use it in my case? Could you please give me an example?